# How can I apply some apache directives based on the original URL before rewrites?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

**General Question:**

Apache allows you to place directives within a `<Location>` section in order to apply them selectively based on the request path. There is also mod-rewrite, which allows you to specify rules for rewriting URLs on the fly.

It seems from my testing that when your URL is modified by a `RewriteRule`, apache uses the rewritten URL to determine which `<Location>` sections should apply. Is there any way to make apache apply directives selectively based on the URL *before* the `RewriteRule` has transformed the URL?

**My specific case:**

I have a web app based on Laravel, which uses a 'front controller' pattern.  All incoming requests that don't correspond to an existing file are re-written to `index.php`, and then this script handles the request.  This is implemented by rules like this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I would like to apply some apache directives only to requests starting with `/foo/`.  So the normal way to do this would be by placing them in a `<Location "/foo/">` section, eg:

```
<Location "/foo/">
    Header always set X-Foo on
</Location>
```

However, when I make a request to `/foo/bar` I find the header is not set.  If I instead use `<Location "/index.php">` then the directives are applied and the header is set. But this is no use to me because *every* URL ends up rewritten to `/index.php`.

Is there any way that I can get a set of directives to be applied based on the original URL `/foo/bar` instead of the rewritten URL `/index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `SetEnvIf` to conditionally set environment variables, then test the variables with `<If>` or `RewriteCond`. For example,

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/foo/ FOO=1
<If "%{ENV:FOO} == 1">
  Header always set X-Foo on
</If>
```

This works as long as the `SetEnvIf` comes "earlier" than any `RewriteRule`. The [SetEnvIf documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) has details.

You might also try just

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo/#">
  Header always set X-Foo on
</If>
```

See [Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html). It might work. The Apache documentation is unfortunately not at all clear about this kind of thing - whether the `If` expression will be evaluated before or after any URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Andrew, but neither one is working for me (on Apache 2.4.6).  `SetEnvIf` is matching against the rewritten URL (index.php), and so is `%{REQUEST_URI}`.  I can't see anything in the documentation for SetEnvIf that says when this directive is processed compared to rewrites or anything else.

Comment: Sorry, further to my previous comment... apparently SetEnvIf *is* matching against the original URL, but after the front controller rewrite, apache is changing the name of the environment variable that was set from `FOO` to `REDIRECT_FOO` (! what?!), so my subsequent `<If>` block was not working.  I've changed it to `<If "%{ENV:REDIRECT_FOO} == 1">` and this is matching and the header is set. I can't find any documentation about this behaviour, just a few people in forums mentioning it.  PS it seems that after the redirect, the `SetEnvIf` rules are processed for a second time with the new URL.